# Bitbucket Pipelines for FTP server

Tags: git, phpstorm, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm currently at a firm that uses PhpStorm sync to deploy code to a server, and uses the branches only on the Bitbucket cloud.

That syncing by hand is very annoying, also if you delete a file it wants to download it back again with a sync from PhpStorm.

So I wanted to use pipelines from Bitbucket to deploy to the server.

(I have found git FTP) But let's say, if a git branch is on the server for example: `root/htdocs/example.com<master branch>` do I still need to do a `git init` with pipelines or a push command (I don't know if an update command can be done as well?)

I know a new project must have a `git init`, but all the projects are existing ones.

If I must use the push command, will it remove the file from the branch and server as well if deleted?

And for my mental picture, is the image just being used to execute certain code? Because I see sometimes that people use unzip in there commands and others do not use it. All do install the git ftp.

And as last, what is the main difference between PhpStorm sync and pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

Your bitbucket pipelines check out the git sources automatically on running.

What you can do is to use rsync from your pipelines to your FTP server.

Check out this solution:
https://medium.com/@Snaverz/bitbucket-pipelines-code-deploy-using-rsync-1f4d1a490170